# js file not loading giving ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel/Vue3 project. For some reason I cannot get the right link to public/js/app.js.

My blade file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">
        
        <map-app/>
    </div>
    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

In my .env file:

```
APP_URL=https://www.evenuitrusten.nl
ASSET_URL=${APP_URL}/bankjesserver/public
```

I then get the error:

```
GET https://www.evenuitrusten.nl/bankjesserver/public/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Where index.html is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">
        
        <map-app/>
    </div>
    <script src="https://www.evenuitrusten.nl/bankjesserver/public/js/app.js"></script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

On my server, the url to app.js is

```
/home/blabla/domains/evenuitrusten.nl/bankjesserver/public/js
```

The URL in the script tag looks correct. Why am I getting a 404?

I tried all kinds of variations of Asset_URL, but non of them worked.

I tried to simplify the problem bij putting a test.js file in the same folder as my  maps.blade.php. This file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        
        <map-app/>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./test.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='{{ asset('js/app.js') }}'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

But also this line leads to a 4040 and teh test.js is not downloaded.

Comment: Does `https://www.evenuitrusten.nl/bankjesserver/js/app.js` work?

Comment: No. I am getting a 404 again.

Comment: What is the goal of `bankjesserver` part of the url? Are you trying to host multiple laravel sites under a single domain?

Comment: There is another domain that has nothing to do with this project. It is just a redirect to a different website.

Comment: As you can see I added another <script> point to  a JS file that only contains a console.log command. It gives the same 404 message.

Comment: When I run the project locally (php artisan serve) the js file loads without problems.

Comment: what webserver are you using?

Comment: Ik draai op bij Keurigonline. Ik denk Linux.

Comment: Just checked. Linux for sure.